looking for a smarter way to go though querySelectorAll nodelist (in GTM)
Tried a lot of solutions (like these https://dev.to/dailydevtips1/javascript-loop-queryselectorall-results-j6) but can't get the loop to work in GTM/Google Tag Manager.
My working script - not very good of course
var helloUrl = document.querySelectorAll('a[id*="hellotracklink"]')[0];


helloUrl.href = helloUrl.href + '?utm_source=' + utm_source + '&utm_medium=' + utm_medium +  '&utm_campaign=' + utm_campaign + '&utm_term=' + utm_term + '&utm_content=' + utm_content + '&lpurl=' + lpUrl;
  
var helloUrl = document.querySelectorAll('a[id*="hellotracklink"]')[1];

helloUrl.href = helloUrl.href + '?utm_source=' + utm_source + '&utm_medium=' + utm_medium +  '&utm_campaign=' + utm_campaign + '&utm_term=' + utm_term + '&utm_content=' + utm_content + '&lpurl=' + lpUrl;
  
var helloUrl = document.querySelectorAll('a[id*="hellotracklink"]')[2];

helloUrl.href = helloUrl.href + '?utm_source=' + utm_source + '&utm_medium=' + utm_medium +  '&utm_campaign=' + utm_campaign + '&utm_term=' + utm_term + '&utm_content=' + utm_content + '&lpurl=' + lpUrl;
  
var helloUrl = document.querySelectorAll('a[id*="hellotracklink"]')[3];

helloUrl.href = helloUrl.href + '?utm_source=' + utm_source + '&utm_medium=' + utm_medium +  '&utm_campaign=' + utm_campaign + '&utm_term=' + utm_term + '&utm_content=' + utm_content + '&lpurl=' + lpUrl;



My failing script in GTM*

var helloUrl = document.querySelectorAll('.hellotracklink');

  
  for (var i = 0; i < helloUrl.length; i++) {
  helloUrl.href = helloUrl.href + '?utm_source=' + utm_source + '&utm_medium=' + utm_medium + '&utm_campaign=' + utm_campaign + '&utm_term=' + utm_term + '&utm_content=' + utm_content + '&lpurl=' + lpUrl;
}


yes indeed, there are multiple elements with that class on the page, but also this one isn't working

In your second (failing) script, helloUrl.href should be helloUrl[i].href, shouldn't it?

try it bro
   var helloUrls = document.querySelectorAll('.hellotracklink');

   for (var i = 0; i < helloUrls.length; i++) {
       var helloUrl = helloUrls[i];
       helloUrl.href += '?utm_source=' + utm_source + '&utm_medium=' + 
       utm_medium + '&utm_campaign=' + utm_campaign + '&utm_term=' + utm_term 
       + '&utm_content=' + utm_content + '&lpurl=' + lpUrl;
      }


By implementing these corrections, your script should correctly loop through all elements with the class hellotracklink and update their href attributes with the appropriate UTM parameters.

You're almost there with your failing script in GTM, but you're missing the indexing for every single element in the NodeList that querySelectorAll returned. Utilizing helloUrl[i], you must access each element inside the loop. Here's the updated script:
var helloUrls = document.querySelectorAll('.hellotracklink');

for (var i = 0; i < helloUrls.length; i++) {
    var helloUrl = helloUrls[i];
    helloUrl.href = helloUrl.href + '?utm_source=' + utm_source + '&utm_medium=' + utm_medium + '&utm_campaign=' + utm_campaign + '&utm_term=' + utm_term + '&utm_content=' + utm_content + '&lpurl=' + lpUrl;
}

This will loop through all the elements with the class .hellotracklink, and for each one, it will append the query parameters to the href attribute as intended.

The answers telling you to loop (iterate) over the nodes are correct, but there's another change you can make that makes it more reliable.
First, would be to structure your utm parameters.
const utmParameters = {
  utm_source,
  utm_medium,
  utm_campaign,
  utm_term,
  utm_content,
  lpUrl,
}

Then you can set those programmatically, to avoid hard to debug string templating issues, you don't need to worry about the question marks and &s and you can preserve other query parameter. This is also easier to refactor later and write tests for.
  for (let i = 0; i < helloUrls.length; i++) {

    const helloUrl = new URL(helloUrls[i].href);
    let params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);

    for([key, value] of Object.entries(utmParameters)) {
      params.set(key, value)
    } ;
    helloUrl.search = params // javaScript figures out that you want the string automatically.
    helloUrls[i].href = helloUrl
  }



document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(anchor => {
    // Run the snippet and then check out the links
    const url = new URL(anchor.href);
    let params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
    for([key, value] of Object.entries({ testMyParam: '123', anotherParam: 'oh my'})) {
      params.set(key, value)
    } 
        url.search = params;
    anchor.href = url
})
<a href="google.com">Google</a> <a href="mozilla.org">Mozilla</a>



